# Infection of Trojan:Win32/Agent.ABIC

Tags: security, virus

I have AVG on the majority of my network and a few MS security essentials installs.  This bugger has been popping up on MSE on a few PCs and keeps coming back.  I've looked at MS's write up of it but its scant on details. Malware bytes doesn't find anything.  I'm concerned that it may be spreading to other computers and haven't found much information about what it does.

Comment: How large is your network? Looks like it is too new for any useful information yet.

Comment: "Win32/Agent is a generic detection for files that perform various malicious actions on an affected computer.
 
Malicious files detected as variants of Win32/Agent can have virtually any purpose. The behaviors displayed by variants of this malware are highly variable."...http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/Threat/Encyclopedia/Entry.aspx?Name=Win32/Agent